# Counter is not working as intended crossing high or low of session

Tags: pine-script, counter

I have a time session set, and I grab the highest high and lowest low of that session.

In a following time session (after the highest high and lowest low are established) I want to mark the first time price closes above the highest high OR price closes below the lowest low. I only want to mark once during that time window, either when the highest high is broken or when the lowest low is broken.

If I remove the counter, it plots correctly, but it will plot every close above the highest high and below the lowest low. I only want it to plot once during the session, hence I added the counter. When I use the counter, it does not plot at all

```
var counter = 0


if inRegularSession and counter <=0 // If time is within session and xover has not happened yet this session
    bool xover = close > sessionhigh // xover (crossover) if close is greater than session high
    o := xover
    
if o // if close > session high add +1 to counter
    counter := counter +1

if inRegularSession and counter <=0 // If time is within session and xunder has not happened yet this session
    bool xunder = close < sessionlow // xunder (crossunder) if close is less than session low
    u := xunder

if u // if close < session low add +1 to counter
    counter := counter +1

if leaveRegularSession // if we leave the session time reset counter
    counter := 0
    bool xover = false
    o := xover
      
    bool xunder = false
    u := xunder

// Plot circles when price closes above session high or closes below session low    

plotshape(o, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)

plotshape(u, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red  , 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this in a slightly different approach. Since you're not using the `counter` value, we can trade it with a `bool` that will be set to `false` when leaving the session and will be set to `true` whenever a `crossover` has occurred. Then we will check if we are in the session and a crossover or crossunder has happened:

```
var didHadCrossoverSessionHigh = false
var didHadCrossundeSessionLow = false

o = false
u = false

crossOverSessionHigh = ta.crossover(close, sessionhigh)
crossOverSessionLow = ta.crossunder(close, sessionhigh)

if inRegularSession and crossOverSessionHigh and not didHadCrossoverSessionHigh
    didHadCrossoverSessionHigh := true
    o := true

if inRegularSession and crossOverSessionLow and not didHadCrossundeSessionLow
    didHadCrossundeSessionLow := true
    u := true

if leaveRegularSession
    didHadCrossoverSessionHigh := false
    didHadCrossundeSessionLow := false

plotshape(o, style=shape.circle, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)
plotshape(u, style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red  , 0), size=size.tiny, display = display.pane)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up doing and it has worked.